# Create a basic controller Spring MVC in Intellij

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I'm trying to do a **basic controller** for my **Spring MVC app**, but **jsp file does not recognize my variable**. I'm using **Java Based config** and after that I created a servlet.xml for configuration.

Here is my controller:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController extends AbstractController{

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws Exception {
        ModelAndView model= new ModelAndView("home");
        model.addObject("message", "Welcome to my home page!");
        return model;
    }
```

}

myapp-servlet-file:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping"/>

<bean name="/jsp/home.jsp"
      class="com.raulbuzila.controller.HomeController" />
```

And my jsp file:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>RuralPrenor Homepage</title>
</head>

<body>

    ${message}

    <a href="<c:url value="product.jsp" />">Add a product</a> |
    <a href="<c:url value="register.jsp" />">Register</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are you doing, precisely, and what do you expect to happen? Why do you choose to name your bean with a .jsp prefix? That will only add confusion. Why don't you use RequestMapping?

Comment: Why are you defining the controller bean? If you annotate it with `@Controller` just use a `context:component-scan`, and annotate the controller with `RequestMapping`.

Comment: Hi! 
I'm expecting to show "Welcome to my home page" in home.jsp" and it doesn't recognize my variable. I named my bean like that because I was working on a tutorial. This one: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/springmvc/springmvc_beannameurlhandlermapping.htm

Comment: Not only this tutorial is very, very old (and outdated), but it never names a Spring bean with a .jsp suffix

Comment: Could you tell me something newer where can I learn?

Comment: The official spring framework documentation, the official spring guides.